# Qual objetivo de usar UUID (versão 4) como "primary key"?

Tags: banco-de-dados, entity-framework, laravel-eloquent, uuid

Tenho notado que alguns lugares tem trocado o ID (gerado por autoincrement, dependendo do SGDB) por UUID, geralmente usam a versão 4 do UUID que é baseado em um sistema pseudo-aleatório, a pergunta não é sobre problemas de colisão, que em UUID v4 tem chance minima, mas sim a questão da motivação do uso por trás disso, segue alguns exemplos de usos:

### Entity framework

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
[Key]
public Guid Id { get; set; }

...
```

No Entity Core creio que não tem isso ainda, ou talvez não venha a ter, não posso confirmar, não usei ainda, então tem que resolver na aplicação com `protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)` (ou outro meio) e aplicar [**`NEWSEQUENTIALID()`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newsequentialid-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) (ou [**`Guid.NewGuid()`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.newguid?view=netcore-3.1))

### Hibernate

No hibernate creio que seja algo com [geradores](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e2734) algo mais ou menos assim:

```
@Id @GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")

...
```

### Laravel Eloquent

No framework Eloquent usado dentro do Framework Laravel e Lumen (ou até stand-alone) podemos configurar (e geralmente é feito assim) nos Models, com trais ou direto no Model de interesse, sobrescrevendo o método e as propriedades `$keyType` e `$incrementing`:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

...

    protected $keyType = 'string';
    public $incrementing = false;

    protected static function bootHasUuid()
    {
        static::creating(function ($model) {
            if (!$model->getKey()) {
                $model->{$model->getKeyName()} = (string) Str::uuid();
            }
        });
    }
```

---

Quero ressaltar que alguns casos daria até para setar na coluna default sem precisar utilizar a camada da aplicação, como no Postgres-13 que tem gerador de UUID nativo ao invés de postgis-script e talvez no SQL-Server com `NEWSEQUENTIALID()` (não testei nenhum na prática).

Apesar de todos casos de resolver na aplicação (asp.net-mvc, JPA, php) parecem funcionar para coisas simples, mas creio que não tenham boa eficiência para inserção de muitos dados simultaneamente (não sei como funciona o núcleo desses frameworks, só suponho que seja na camada da aplicação que gere o UUID se estiver equivocado pode comentar), mas o questionamento que tenho não é sobre performance e sim qual o objetivo de usarem **UUID versão 4** como ID ao invés de INT+autoincrement.

Seria supostamente para dificultar a identificação sequencial de dados? Por exemplo tenho um ID 23, logo posso presumir um outro ID de um mesmo contexto sendo o 24, e assim por diante?

Ou seria para dificultar deduzir a quantidade de dados?

Ou algum outro motivo?

Comment: O `int` com auto incremento é único para apenas para um banco de dados e apenas uma tabela, já o UUID é universalmente único, mesmo que você faça `select uuid();` em duas maquinas distintas com SGBD distintos os valores retornados pela função serão diferentes. Se você adotar o UUID como identificador você teria uma facilidade na hora de migrar os dados, porque o `int` é único apenas no contexto de sua tabela ou base de dados assim vai ter grandes chances de conflitos quando estiver importando para outra base, já o UUID te da mais garantias numa migração.

Comment: @gato eu concordo com isso, até mesmo o Piovezan citou um link nos comentários aonde o autor aponta essa possibilidade, mas pessoalmente o proprio processo de migração ou junção de dados de diferentes origens para uma nova estrutura ou continuada aonde ocorra um JOIN não é tão complicado de se resolver, se vai ocorrer migração aonde irá unificar dados a propria camada da aplicação terá que ter novos locais, afinal é um novo contexto, então a ideia até parece boa, mas se for para resolver um problema futuro é melhor aprender a resolver o problema futuro sem precisar disso...

Comment: O certo era nem precisar de migração ;D

Comment: ... quero dizer, é como se eu criasse um bot razoavelmente inteligente para propósitos simples, mas eu adicionasse dentro dele uma bomba pq estou com medo dele dominar a humanidade e eu poderia destruir ele se necessário, bem se isso for possivel significa que eu criei um bot exagerado demais para uma tarefa que deveria ser mediana e o problema estaria em outro lugar e deve ser resolvido de outra maneira :P, sei que ilustrar o problema assim pode soar exagerado, mas é assim que me parece a propria ideia de uso do UUID-v4 até o momento.

Comment: Sem comparar com o auto incremento a motivação é que não requer uma [autoridade centralizada](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4122#section-2) para administra-los, tornado cada UUID único e independente de qualquer outra coisa.

Comment: No EF Core você não precisa usar os atributos mencionados em `Id`. Por convenção, essa coluna já será criada como chave primária. Para gerar GUIDs, normalmente é feito no lado do cliente quando não é feito do lado do banco de dados, usando `Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid()`, então todas as entidades criadas terão um id novo.

Answer (score 5):

Pensando em identificadores randômicos quaisquer, independente do padrão, há algumas vantages:

É um **pouco** mais seguro, como dito, um identificador interiro autoincrementado é bem mais simples de saber onde está outros recursos da mesma natureza, se os dados do seu usuário está em `/users/123`, você pode prezumir que provavelmente existe um usuário em `/users/122`, `/users/121`, etc. Já um identificador randômico não é tão simples, ainda sim, nada impede do atacante fazer um script que gera ids aleatórios pra tentar encontrar o recurso buscado.

Ainda sim, isso é apenas uma segurança por obscurantismo (*security through obscurity*), é frágil, se não houver um meio de autenticação e autorização, a falha continua a existir, mas já é uma dificuldade a mais para o atacante. No mundo ideal, os sistemas teriam essa segurança, mas na realidade nem sempre tem, pode-se encontrar sistemas apenas com a autenticação, mas nenhuma verificação de autorização, ou seja, se você está logado, independente do seu usuário, pode fazer qualquer ação, por exemplo, quando é apenas validado se o token é válido

Os identificadores randômicos são infinitos, diferente de inteiros, que são limitados de acordo com o tipo utilizado, ainda sim, um Bigint tem o valor máximo de 9.223.372.036.854.776.000 (no MySQL), que é um valor extremamente alto, mas em um cenário de Big Data de uma grade empresa, pensando a longo prazo, pode ser preferível o identificador randômico

Usar esse tipo de identificadores é bem mais simples quando você tem um sistema de armazenamento de dados distribuido, por exemplo, blockchain e, talvez, banco de leitura e escrita separados (não conheço, mas parece que se encaixa). Outro caso de uso mais comum é quando você precisa identificar unicamente um usuário, sem que ele se cadastre, uma ferramenta como Analytics, se for utilizado uma conexão via socket, poderia ser feito da forma tradicional mantendo a simplicidade, se não, seria desnecessário enviar uma requisição ao servidor apenas para obter um id e então salvar na máquina do cliente, fora que, durante esse tempo, o cliente poderia sair da aplicação e o identificador não ser salvo, sendo necessário gerar um novo para o mesmo cliente

Em um dos links comentados na responsta anterior, é mencionado a vantagem de, como esse identificador costuma (nem sempre) ser criado no lado da aplicação, é possível identificar um recurso criado antes dele ser enviado ao banco de dados, porém, usar esse identificador antes pode gerar problemas, já que não há como garantir que a inserção realmente funcionou, mesmo que a aplicação esteja bem testada, o servidor do banco de dados pode cair, por exemplo, e a complexidade e trabalho para criar um sistema reativo a esse tipo de falha provavelmente não compensa o pouco ganho com isso

Como desvantagem, foi mencionado o tamanho maior ocupado pelo identificador, o que costuma ser verdade, mas não necessariamente, como esses identificadores são criados a partir do timestamp da inserção, alguns deles podem ser transformados na data da inserção (por exemplo, o ObjectId do MongoDB), que é um dado comumente salvo de qualquer forma, então o identificador pode ter o papel de dois campos e a memória ocupada a mais vai ser deduzida pelo campo a menos necessário. Contudo, esse pouco a mais também não deve ser um problema

Answer (score 4):

Vou fazer suposições.

Teoricamente, usando um UUID aleatório você deixa de expor qual é o intervalo aproximado de id's válidos, de 0 a um N máximo encontrado. Não se sabe mais quais e nem quantos são esses id's.

A desvantagem é o aumento do tamanho do campo para o id e sobretudo o espaço ocupado pelo índice criado para essa coluna quando o número de registros de torna grande. Também a dificuldade de se trabalhar com consultas envolvendo UUIDs (só na base do *copy-paste*).

Comment: Entendo, foi o que comentei na propria pergunta, mas me tire uma duvida, que tipo de problema pode ocorrer de expor os intervalos e a sequencia numerica?

Comment: Imagino que seja uma possível falha de segurança, já que esses intervalos costumam ser expostos por exemplo nas URLs de requisições HTTP a webservices REST (exemplo: `DELETE api/produto/3125`), mas estou falando sem experiência prática.

Comment: Entendo, realmente não consigo ver isso como falha e nem como expõe algo, já que esse tipo de problema se resolve dentro da aplicação definindo o que é permissivo a X usuário, o proprio site stackoverflow tem os IDs sequenciais, isso nunca foi uma falha e nem falha explorável, exemplos, sem saber o nome posso acessar o perfil: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/1, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/2, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/3, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/10, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/11, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/12 ... https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/20

Comment: Se um invasor com acesso a um token válido (por exemplo) começar a deletar perfis, com UUID fica mais difícil deduzir o que deletar. Mas novamente estou fazendo suposições, não tenho experiência prática para afirmar.

Comment: Se o Token foi exposto não vai ser isso que vai resolver, a falha já estar em ter um token exposto, porque se tem acesso a isso então por um proprio painel pode existir um sistema de excluir dados, ou perfis, ou qualquer coisa, sem nem precisar de saber os IDs, já que gerenciamento de tudo em um nivel adm de um sistema geralmente é possivel, então a falha ainda é na aplicação e não no ID numerico. Concorda?

Comment: Concordo. Talvez essa leitura seja o que está procurando: https://tomharrisonjr.com/uuid-or-guid-as-primary-keys-be-careful-7b2aa3dcb439